# PHP convert hex to float

Tags: php, floating-point, hex, yii2-advanced-app

Hi I am trying to convert the hex value into float the method I am using is

```
function hex2float($strHex) {
$hex = sscanf($strHex, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x");
$hex = array_reverse($hex);
$bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $hex));
$array = unpack("dnum", $bin);
return $array['num'];
}

$float = hex2float('4019999a');
echo $float;
```

**Output**

The output it's returning is `6.4000015258789` but in actual it should be `2.4`

See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690813/8919244)

Comment: I vote to reopen this as the question isn't actually about precision. It's about little endian versus big endean byte order.

Comment: The representation here can be either 2.4 or 6.33 depending on endianess. For example, `var_dump(unpack('G*', hex2bin('4019999a'))[1]);` gives you `float(2.4000000953674)` whereas `var_dump(unpack('g*', hex2bin('4019999a'))[1]);` would give you `float(-6.3320110435437E-23)`. One is little endian and the other is big endian.

Comment: @Sherif how can I get exact `2.4` as this value is sent from the client machine?

Comment: There is no such thing as exactly value in floating point math. This is why we have precision settings. A single precision float only has 7 digits of precision whereas a double precision float (what PHP casts the value to internally) has 15 digits of precision. You took a single precision float and stored it in a double precision float. The extra digits come from the fact that your single precision float is too small fit in a double precision float. Notice there are exactly 6 zeros after the 4 there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are interpreting the value in little endian byte order. This gives you the incorrect value of `6.4`, which is actually `-6.3320110435437E-23`. Additionally, you are unpacking this as a double-precision float. It's not. It's single precision (only 4 bytes wide).

```
function hex2float($strHex) {
    $hex = sscanf($strHex, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x");
    $bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $hex));
    $array = unpack("Gnum", $bin);
    return $array['num'];
}

$float = hex2float('4019999a');
echo $float;
```

This gives you the correct value of 2.4.

An easier way to do this is `var_dump(unpack('G', hex2bin('4019999a'))[1]);` which also gives you the correct value.

Comment: Using `sscanf()` and `implode()` is unnecessary, you can just `$bin = hex2bin($strHex);` directly.

Comment: @Sherif the value I am getting is `2.4000000953674`, but the actual value passed from the client is `2.4`

Comment: Yes, they're the same value. `2.4000000953674` rounds to `2.4`. Welcome to floating point arithmetic.